# Brushless DC motor stalls at startup

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, resonance, startup-issues

I have two small fans with brushless 12 V DC motors connected in series. Each motor has a flyback diode. Also in series is a small resistor to bring the voltage down slightly from 28 V, which is the power supply. The circuit is turned on with a transistor (ULN 2003A).

Turning on works most of the time, but sometimes both the fans get stuck vibrating and will not start to turn, unless I give one of them a spin with my hand. Trying to understand why, and what I can do about it.

I've tried to bypass the resistor, has no effect, so lack of startup current doesn't seem to be the problem. Do they get into some kind of resonance circuit?

[image]

Comment: What current can your supply give? Where's the motors' datasheets? What control method do the motors use? Are they sensorless or hall effect or something else?

Comment: 2 fans 12V wired in series? Are they the same? Are the fans "decoupled" with a capacitor?

Comment: @Puffafish: Simple on/off control (no PWM). 

https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productfile/41018/MF50151V3-1000U-A99.pdf

Comment: @Antonio51: No capacitor. See above, I added a schematic to the question.

Comment: @Puffafish: Supply has internal resistance of max 1 ohm: 5 m of AWG20 cable connected to large LiFePO4 battery.

Comment: You should add 2 equal capacitors perhaps 10 -> 100 uF (one in parallel with each fan).

Comment: @Antonio51: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Supply would be applied "simultaneously" on the two motors and ... equally.

Comment: Please don’t run two fans in series. If load becomes unbalanced for whatever reason, one of the fans will receive almost 28 V across it which is out of spec. Moreover, the stall current of the fan(s) will “fight” your 200 ohm resistor and could be the reason why it won’t start. Get yourself a 24 V fan instead.

Comment: The answer is that you shouldn't do this. The fans will not receive a steady DC voltage, which is what they are designed to work with. Use a step down regulator and put them in parallel. Or buy different fans.